# Can I schedule UpdateClusterInternal in GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, upgrade, google-kubernetes-engine

This [upgrade policy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/versioning-and-upgrades#automatic_master_upgrades) from GCP is too aggressive for me, I only use 1 node pool with 1 single node. When the upgrade happens, my system is entirely down.

Is there a way to:

- Disable automatic upgrade? or
- Schedule the upgrade to the exact date/time? or
- Tell Google that if they want to update please add a new temporary node in the node pool first? or
- At least notify me via email a few days/hours before the upgrade so I can add a new node by myself?

These master node upgrades caused 1+ hour of downtime to my system twice, I'm really frustrated.

Comment: If you want high availability, you need redundancy.  Upgrades aren't the only reason a single node can disappear without warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GKE Master Nodes are managed by Google, it is not possible for customers to [disable auto-upgrading](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster#upgrading_the_master).

GKE does offer a Maintenance Window feature, which provides you with additional controls for when [maintenance happens](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/maintenance-windows-and-exclusions.) 
I would suggest you to have a look into the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-upgrading-your-clusters-with-zero-downtime) for upgrading the clusters. It might help you to decide solution for your concern.

Besides this, Upgrading a node pool may disrupt workloads running in that node pool. To avoid this, you can create a [new node pool with the desired version](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster) and migrate the workload. After migration, you can delete the old node pool.

Unfortunately, there is no timeframe available for upgrades. Hope this information helps.